# Proving $ \liminf x_n=2 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ {x_n} $ be a real sequence, defined by, 
$x_n =
\begin{cases}
2+\frac{1}{n},  & \text{if $n=m^{2}$ for some $ m\in \mathbb{N} $} \\
n+1, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

Here I need to prove that $ \liminf x_n=2 $. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: what is $\lim \frac{1}{n}$ as $n \to \inf$

Answer (score 2):

**Proof:** Let $ \epsilon >0 $. Observe that for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, $n+1>2-\epsilon $ and $2+\frac{1}{n}>2-\epsilon $. Hence for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, $ x_n>2-\epsilon $.

Now let $ m\in \mathbb{N} $ and choose $ k\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $k>\max \left\lbrace m,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right\rbrace $. Put $n=k^{2}$.

Then $ n\in \mathbb{N},n>m $ and $ x_n=x_{k^{2}}=2+\frac{1}{k^{2}}<2+\epsilon $.

Therefore we have shown that for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, $ x_n>2-\epsilon $ and for each $ m\in \mathbb{N} $, there exists $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ suth that $ n>m $ and $ x_n<2+\epsilon $. Hence we have $ \liminf x_n=2 $.